# XSLT: Get row element inside a for-loop over one table from another table

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have three tables in my XML file: `tableX`, `tableA` and `tableB`.

This is my algorithm:

- Go through each row element of `tableX` and check, if `Xelement1` is `NULL` (empty).
- If match:

  - Go through each row in `tableA` and compare the value of the row element `Aelement2` with another row element `Xelement2` of `tableX`.
  - If match:

    - Go through each row element of `tableB` and compare the value of row element `Belement1` of`tableB` with the value of the row element `Aelement1` of `tableA`
    - If match:

      - Print a value of another row element `Belement2` of `tableB`

Currently I am doing this and it is working:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableX']/row">
  <xsl:variable name="rec" select="."/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Xelement1=''">
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableA']/row">
        <xsl:variable name="member" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="Aelement2=$rec/Xelement2">
          <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableB']/row">
            <xsl:if test="Belement1=$member/Aelement1">
              <xsl:value-of select="Belement2"/>&#160
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- Xelement1 is not null -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, I wish I could access e.g. `Aelement1` within the third `for-each` loop, without having to save it to a variable `member`.

Also, why doesn't this work?

```
    [...]
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableA']/row">
        <xsl:variable name="member" select="Aelement1"/>
        <xsl:if test="Aelement2=$rec/Xelement2">
          <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableB']/row">
            <xsl:if test="Belement1=$member">
              <xsl:value-of select="Belement2"/>&#160
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    [...]
```

Minimal, but complete XML example:

```
<root>
    <table name="tableX">
      <row>
        <Xelement1>11</Xelement1>
        <Xelement2>3</Xelement2>
        <Xother>failure</Xother>
      </row>
      <row>
        <Xelement1>NULL</Xelement1>
        <Xelement2>9</Xelement2>
        <Xother>success</Xother>
      </row>
  </table>
  <table name="tableA">
    <row>
      <Aelement1>10</Aelement1>
      <Aelement2>16</Aelement2>
      <Aother>failure</Aother>
    </row>
    <row>
      <Aelement1>12</Aelement1>
      <Aelement2>9</Aelement2>
      <Aother>success</Aother>
    </row>
    <row>
      <Aelement1>12</Aelement1>
      <Aelement2>16</Aelement2>
      <Aother>failure</Aother>
    </row>
    <row>
      <Aelement1>14</Aelement1>
      <Aelement2>9</Aelement2>
      <Aother>success</Aother>
    </row>
  </table>
  <table name="tableB">
    <row>
      <Belement1>10</Belement1>
      <Belement2>failure</Belement2>
      <Bother>random</Bother>
    </row>
    <row>
      <Belement1>12</Belement1>
      <Belement2>success</Belement2>
      <Bother>random</Bother>
    </row>
    <row>
      <Belement1>14</Belement1>
      <Belement2>success</Belement2>
      <Bother>random</Bother>
    </row>
  </table>
</root>
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal but complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  example of your XML input and of the expected result.

Comment: OK, done. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: "*Here, Aelement=Belement=5 should match.*" Ok, so they match. Then what? Do you want to do something with the matching row in table A or in table B? IOW, what is the expected result?

Comment: Ok I updated my answer to fit your question in your comment above. I will edit now my expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to select the corresponding rows from table B with a single XPath expression:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name = 'tableB']/row[
  Belement = /root/table[@name = 'tableA']/row/Aelement
]">
  <!-- Do something -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

This works because XPath's `=`, when operating on node-sets, compares all nodes on the left-hand side with all nodes on the right-hand side (just like an INNER JOIN in SQL).

It will select one node in your example (namely the `<row>` that has `<Belement>5</Belement>`), but it would select more if there were more matches.

---

After a substantial edit to the question, the XPath expression got more complex. The same principle applies.

```
//table[@name = 'tableB']/row[
  Belement1 = //table[@name = 'tableA']/row[
    Aelement2 = //table[@name = 'tableX']/row[
      Xelement1 = 'NULL'
    ]/Xelement2
  ]/Aelement1
]/Belement2
```

will select the elements containing `"success"` from your sample.

Read it from the inside out:

- from the `tableX` rows with `Xelement1 = 'NULL'` you want the `Xelement2`
- from the `tableA` rows where `Aelement2` corresponds to those you want `Aelement1`
- from the `tableB` rows where `Belement1` corresponds to those you want `Belement2`

Comment: I updated my question, because my question was missing crucial information. Can you update your answer please? :)

Comment: Changing your question substantially in mid-flight amounts to wasting other people's time. That's not very nice. :-/

Comment: Yeah sorry :(. My problem is still the same, but I thought leaving other code out of the scope will make the question more read-able. I was wrong! I have a if statement before the second for-each loop, which will be ignored, if I am using a for-each loop as stated above.

Comment: @polym See modified answer.

Comment: Can you explain why it is `//table` and not `/root/table`? Does it glob to the next node level? Also what should I do, if I want to do something else in the first for-each loop?

Comment: `//` is the shorthand for `descendant-or-self::node()`. It searches through the entire tree (if you happen to know the exact, absolute path to the table then of course you can use that as well)

Comment: Cool :)! I understood your code, thanks to your inside-out description, tried to adapt it to my code (with some little alterations) and it worked. Thank you for updating your answer! Next time I'll try to be more concrete. Oh one little question: ...]/Belement2  -> This should print out all Belement2? I currently use value-of, because adding /element doesn't print the desired element in a for-each. Should it?

Comment: Well, it *selects* all matching `<Belement2>` in any case. What you do with them afterwards is up to you. If you do `<xsl:value-of select=".">` inside the `<xsl:for-each>` then yes, with your sample input it would print the string `'success'` two times. A definitive answer kinda depends on where you want to go from those `<Belement2>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a key

```
<xsl:key name="row" match="table[@name = 'tableB']/row" use="Belement"/>
```

then you can shorten

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableA']/row">
  <xsl:variable name="member" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableB']/row">
    <xsl:if test="Belement=$member/Aelement">
      <!--Do something-->
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableA']/row/key('row', Aelement)">
      <!--Do something-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

As for the terminology, your code processes `row` `elements` or `row` `element nodes`.

As for the sample that is not working, you would need to show us minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, result you want, result you get so that we can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated my question, because my question was missing crucial information. Sorry! Can you update your answer please :)? I have a if statement before the second for-each loop, which will be ignored, if I am using a for-each loop as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, why doesn't this work?

```
> <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableA']/row">  
>   <xsl:variable name="member" select="Aelement"/>   
>   <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableB']/row">
>     <xsl:if test="Belement=$member">
>       <!--Do something-->
>     </xsl:if>
>   </xsl:for-each>
> </xsl:for-each>
```

Actually, it **does** work. If you try actually doing something with the matching row in tableB, for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableA']/row">
            <xsl:variable name="member" select="Aelement"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/table[@name='tableB']/row">
                <xsl:if test="Belement=$member">
                    <!--Do something-->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <row>
      <Belement>5</Belement>
    </row>
</output>
```

Comment: I updated my question, because crucial information was missing.